# Is there a difference between array templates and built in array types?

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors

I have a C++ class I wrote called "Encrypt".  The class has several functions, including a constructor, which interact with an array data member, and also accept an array as an argument.  According to the book I'm reading, it is preferred to use the array template and create arrays like below, rather than using the "built in" array notation.

How my book says to create an array:

```
std::array <int, 8> digits;
```

How I've created arrays in the past:

```
int digits[8];
```

I have the array definition (my first example) contained as a private data member of my class.  I included a constructor that accepts an array and uses that array to store data in my private data member array.  My constructor prototype looks like this:

```
Encrypt(std::array <int, 8>);
```

The problem is, my teacher supplied a .cpp driver file that passes an array to my constructor.  The way he declared his array is as follows:

```
int Long[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
```

So, he used the old "built in" array notation.  He called my constructor by creating an object and supplying the array base address, like so:

```
Encrypt objName(Long);
```

When I try to compile my program, I get the following error:

```
error C2664: 'Encrypt::Encrypt(const Encrypt &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int[8]' to '_int64'
```

So my guess is that an array created using the built in array notation is not the same as an array constructed from the  template.  I'm not sure if I'm missing something, because I don't understand why my teacher would use an array that is not compatible with what the book says to do (this is an online class, so I teach myself from the book).

Here is my "MCVE" as requested - please comment if I left something out - I tried to condense my class to only the code that matters.

Contents in my .h file:

```
class Encrypt
{
public:
   Encrypt(long long int);             // class constructor to store last 4 digits of input
   Encrypt(std::array <int, 8>);       // second class constructor to store first 4 digits
private:
    std::array <int, 8> digits;  // data member array to hold digit inputs and encrypted data
};
```

Contents of my .cpp class implementation file (stripped of unrelated code):

```
#include "Encrypt.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;
// begin first constructor - accepts int input and stores last for digits
Encrypt::Encrypt(long long int input)  // constructor 1 - encrypts and stores data
{
   // removed code to store int argument into private data member array
} // end first constructor

// begin constructor 2 - accepts array and stores first 4 digits
Encrypt::Encrypt(array <int, 8> input)       
{
  // removed code that performs various operations on argument array and
  // private data member array
} // end of second constructor
```

Code that calls my constructor, supplied by my teacher in .cpp "driver" file:

```
#include "Encrypt.h" // include definition of class Encrypt
#include "Decrypt.h" // include definition of class Decrypt
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::atoi;


int main()
{  int Long[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
int Negative[]={-8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
Encrypt eapp1(0), eapp2(40), eapp3(4560), eapp4(6145698),eapp5(-6), 
    eapp6(Long), eapp7(Negative); // create Encrypt objects

// more code to test program

return 0;
} // end of main
```

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The error you've shown is being reported in the copy ctor, not in a ctor taking an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't freely exchange a C-style array and an `<array>` template, they are different things.

But you can access the underlying array with the `data()` member function :

```
void Encrypt(int* a)
{
    // ....
}

int main(void)
{
    std::array <int, 8> digits;
    Encrypt(digits.data());

    int digits2[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    Encrypt(digits2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With strong type you may use the following:

```
class Encrypt
{
public:
    Encrypt(const std::array<int, 8>& a) : mArray(a) {}
#ifdef OPTION1
    Encrypt(const int (&a)[8]) : mArray({a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7]}) {}
#else
    Encrypt(const int (&a)[8]) { std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(mArray)); }
#endif

private:
    std::array<int, 8> mArray;
};
```

(You can see why `std::array` is preferred over raw array).